# How would you solve this finite-state-machine (Moore)?

Tags: state-machine

I am trying to solve an exercise using Moore's machine, but I am a bit confused. I don't know how many states are needed.

Inputs:

- A (switch): change between auto and manual mode.
- P (push-button): give high level while is pressed.
- D (motion detector): give high level if detect movement

Outputs:

- L (lamp).

Conditions:

- If we are in manual mode, L will change (from 0 to 1) or (1 to 0) if we push "P". We need to re-press the button to change the L again (it is not valid hold the finger).
- If we are in automatic mode, L will be enabled while "D" detect movement.
- User will never push "A" and "P" at the same time.
- When you change from auto to manual or manual to auto, the lamp have to pass low level.
- When you change from auto to manual, the lamp will stay with a high level while detect movement.

The big problems are the last conditions. I don't know how can I handle them. Do I need to create extra-states for those conditions? What steps would you follow to solve the exercise?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by the second-to-last condition?  What happens if the A switch is toggled while the lamp is on?

Comment: @augurar The lamp will have to through the turn off state in the transition and then it will work normally again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, design separate finite state machines for the automatic and manual case.  The automatic case needs only two states (lamp on or off).  The manual case needs 4 states to keep track of whether the button has been released since the last press.

Then add transitions between these machines based on the value of the switch A.  Only add transitions between states where the lamp is off.  This will ensure that the last two conditions hold.  If the lamp is on when A is toggled, nothing will happen until the machine transitions to a "lamp off" state.

Comment: Thank you I am doing it.

Comment: To hold the second-to-last condition I will need to create a transition from manual (turned off) to auto (turned off) and another transition from manual (turned on) to auto (turned off). Is this correct?
To hold the last condition I will need to create a transition from the first and third state of auto to turned on state of manual mode. Is this correct? Did I explain well? Thank you again.

Comment: @AlbertoFernández The "auto" switch should not change the state of the lamp.  And we know we should only transition between modes when the lamp is off.  Thus, transitions between auto and manual should only connect "off" states in each mode.